# With Python Library 'requests', Can I succeed to login at the site's login page which uses JSEncrypt function for id and pw?

Tags: python, authentication, encryption, python-requests

When I look at the Chrome development tools at the login page, the JS code executing login function was below

'''

```
     axboot.ajax({
            method   : 'POST',
            url      : '/usr/cmn/login/LoginSecurity.do',
            callback : function(res) {
                
                var login = JSON.stringify({ 'loginId': $('#loginId').val(), 'loginPwd': $('#loginPwd').val(), 'storeIdYn': storeIdYn });
                
                var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
                encrypt.setPublicKey(res.publicKey);
                var loginToken = encrypt.encrypt(login);
                
                axboot.ajax({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url    : '/usr/cmn/login/LoginConfirm.do',
                    data   : JSON.stringify({ 'loginToken': loginToken, 'redirectUrl': '', 'redirectTabUrl': '' }),
                    options: {
                        nomask  : false,
                        apiType : 'login'
                    },
```

'''

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(res.publicKey);
var loginToken = encrypt.encrypt(login);
```

For this JS Encrypting code, I was supposed to encrypt in python code and post it as data for the LoginConfirm url

But I am not sure for this method.

And I am wondering there is a way to solve this login Scraping problem!!

Comment: that library does RSA encryption. you can do that in python with [crypto](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.import_key)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I will try it

Comment: @Nullman What does the options mean in ajax ?

Comment: I don't know what `options` are in ajax. I'm not an expert on js. are you using [axboot](https://api.axboot.com/front-end/axboot.js.html)? you can try reading the documentation, I cannot read korean

Comment: Thanks..! Actually options are related with axboot...lol